# Problem pubishing in JBOSS, links to files (images, subpages) HTML with aboslute path redirect to / instead APP

Tags: javascript, html, jboss, wildfly, jboss7.x

I got an EAR file, I try to deploy and It deploys fine, without error. The problem is the following:

All the ccs files, images, files, etc are using absolute paths in the HTML files, (the HTML files are being generated through an external program so change to relative paths is not an option), so the styles are not being loaded, the links to other pages don't work, etc.

An example to clarity:

I have the ear deployed in "localhost:8080/app, the index.html file loads but inside the file, I try to use the link to the page2.html, and the path is localhost:8080/page2.html instead "localhost:8080/app/page2.html".

The browser says "the page cannot be loaded"

How can I fix this without change the paths to relative? I have the context root of application.xml with "app" and the welcome file of web.xml inside the war file with "index.html".

the structure is the following:

file.ear
 meta-inf
 file.war
  web-inf
  index.html
  css folder
  pageX.html

I beg for help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what is the tech stack you are using ? (front-end, back-end)

Comment: Hi Yogendra123 sorry but I am using an static website, I am deploying using Jboss 7.1, I think it is front.end but my knowledge is limited. The HTMl files have absolute root paths instead of realtive paths. Is there a way to set in the Ear configuration files that the root path is "/app" and is it not "/"? thanks! :)

Comment: It's difficult to answer without seeing your code. Can you share your code via git repo ?

Comment: Hello, What do you need exaclty? :) I have a lot of files of code, I thnik you need the structure and the web-inf and meta-inf content right? or do you need the data in WebContent too? Thanks a lot

Comment: are you using any build tool ?

Comment: I am using Eclipse, I created a maven web-app project and it generated the structure.  Then I executed the "Run as " and Maven build module. I executed the generated a new Enterprise Module and associated the Maven project, I loaded the ear in jboss and works the index.hml but the other webpage elements have the path "/page" instead of "/App/page".Tell me the files that you need :)

Comment: It would be helpful, if you create a git repo with minimum files required to run you app, so that I could reproduce the error.

Comment: Hello, I shared the ear in https://github.com/jemova/jemovademo you can unzip the ear an see the content or try to deploy it directly. I will be waiting for you. Thanks again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to know understand, how file system works in web.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="slick.css"> // file present in same folder
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/slick-theme.css"> // file present in css folder of current folder
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/slick-theme.css"> // file present in the css folder at the root directory of the current web
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../slick-theme.css"> // file present at one level up the current folder
```

Since all your files path starts with `/`, server tries to find it relative to the root directory.

All you need is to deploy your app as root app without any context-root.

This will require 2 things:

1)

```
<context-root>/</context-root>
```

2) configuration change at server level, remove default content mapping, try to find

```
<location name="/" handler="welcome-content"/>
```

(may vary in your jboss version) and comment it.

Attaching screenshot of your working app:
[image]

PS: Delete your EAR from repo or make it private

Comment: Thanks a lot. I understand that with this code i cannot set a context root, this server has more apps so context root is needed. I cannot modify the files of the web app because they are generated by another software so I cannot change the paths to relative. I set your answer as correct because you helped me to understand. Have a nice day.

Answer (score 0):

Deploy your app as ROOT.war

You might also need to tweak your server config to allow this if you keep seeing the server welcome page

Comment: Hello, I did and I can see now the header of the page, but I cannot see anything else (format and images have the broken symbol), If I look for the soruce of the image, It stills is localhost:8080/img/peptito.jpg instead of localhost:8080/app/img/pepito.jpg. I modified the application.xml with ROOT,war value and changed the name of the war to ROOT.war. When you mean configure the server, what do you mean exactly? thanks for your help, I appreciate it a lot.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't bind the app to / and you can't change the file paths referenced in the app, then the only option would be to use a proxy infront of the sever, something like nginx, so you make the requests to the proxy and it passes the request on to http://appserver/app/